# iPhone Call History and App store

Tags: ios, logging, call

I would like to know if Apple will allow reading the call log history database on iPhone in application that will be submitted to the App Store.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no supported method for accessing the call log on iOS devices, and no way you can achieve this or submit an app doing this to the App Store legitimately.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an existing official documented API, you may use it. It's as simple as that.